# How to get a vector or matrix output to workspace using simulink?

Tags: matlab, vector, simulink, state-space

This is a fairly simple thing I think, but I cannot seem to get the right output that Im looking for. I am using matrices to represent state space models in simulink, and I am trying to get my states output to the workspace,

it is a simple 4x1 vector, and I tried just using the regular "to workspace" block, but it seems it concats to either a 2d or 3d vector..

I want to have a tx4 matrix output that I can reference the first state and plot for all simulation time(t) like x(:,1), the second state x(:,2) etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [save format](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html#buabxvb-1) in a `To Workspace` block. Default this is set to `timeseries`, but you can set it to `Array`.

Looking at the doc for the Array setting:

> If the input signal is a scalar or a vector, each input sample is output as a row of the array. Suppose that the name of the output array is `simout`. Then, `simout(1,:)` corresponds to the first sample, `simout(2,:)` corresponds to the second sample, and so on.

You want the first dimension not to be time, but your state vector, so transposing `simout` should do the trick.

```
simout = simout.';    % or tranpose(simout);
```